# Keep toolbar while changing screens kivy

Tags: python, kivy, toolbar

So I have a toolbar and it I want to use it to change between screens, but I want it to stay there while I'm freely changing the screens.
If I try to put a GridLayout inside a ScreenManager class it gives me an error, so instead I'm creating a GridLayout and embedding a Screen Manager into it. But it doesn't seems to work the way I want it to.

storeapp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class ScreenSwitcher(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenSwitcher, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='sone'))
        self.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='stwo'))

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    manager = ScreenSwitcher()

class StoreApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    StoreApp().run()
```

store.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<ToolBar@BoxLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 35
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'y': 0}
    padding: 5,2,5,2
    spacing: 5

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, 1, .7, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ToolButton@Button>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    align: 'center'

<ScreenOne>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN ONE'
        font_size:50

<ScreenTwo>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN TWO'
        font_size:50

<MainScreen>:
    rows: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1

    ToolBar:
        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen one'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'sone'

        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen two'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'stwo'

    ScreenSwitcher:
```

PROBLEM: the two screens are overlapping and pressing the buttons doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's a solution here: [Python Kivy screen manager wiget scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613955/python-kivy-screen-manager-wiget-scope)

But I just found out that there's no easy to understand explanations for beginners out there on how to do this, so here it goes mine:

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class ScreenSwitcher(ScreenManager):
     #The screens can be added on the __init__ method like this or on the .kv file
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenSwitcher, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='sone'))
        self.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='stwo'))

#Can be moved to another file, but needs to be imported
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

#Can be moved to another file, but needs to be imported
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    pass

class StoreApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    StoreApp().run()
```

kivy file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<ToolBar@BoxLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 35
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'y': 0}
    padding: 5,2,5,2
    spacing: 5

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, 1, .7, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ToolButton@Button>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    align: 'center'

#Can be moved to another file if included with #:include filename.kv
<ScreenOne>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN ONE'
        font_size:50

#Can be moved to another file if included with #:include filename.kv
<ScreenTwo>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN TWO'
        font_size:50

#GridLayout used to separate the toolbar from the App's screens
<MainScreen>:
    rows: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1

    ToolBar:
        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen one'
            on_press:
                root.ids.SS.current = 'sone'
                #Use root.ids to find the ID of your ScreenManager class and 
                #use it to call what you want from there

        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen two'
            on_press:
                root.ids.SS.current = 'stwo'
                #Use root.ids to find the ID of your ScreenManager class and
                #use it to call what you want from there

    ScreenSwitcher:
        id: SS #Put an ID to your ScreenManager class
        #instead of adding the screens on the __init__method you can also do
        #ScreenOne:
        #ScreenTwo:
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The Kivy App is not switching screen because there are two instances of *ScreenSwitcher*. One instance was instantiated in the kv file by `ScreenSwitcher:`. The second instance was instantiated in the Python script by `manager = ScreenSwitcher()`.

The button's *on_press* event was referencing the second instance of *ScreenSwitcher*.

## Solution

### store.py

1. Add `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`.
2. Replace `manager = ScreenSwitcher()` with `manager = ObjectProperty(None)`

```
class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)
```

### store.kv

1. Add `manager: manager` after `<MainScreen>:`. This is to hook-up *ObjectProperty* to *ScreenSwitcher*'s id.
2. Add `id: manager` after `ScreenSwitcher:`

```
<MainScreen>:
    manager: manager
    rows: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1

    ...

    ScreenSwitcher:
        id: manager
```

Please refer to the example and output for details.

## Example

### store.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)


class StoreApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StoreApp().run()
```

### store.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<ToolBar@BoxLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 35
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'y': 0}
    padding: 5,2,5,2
    spacing: 5

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, 1, .7, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ToolButton@Button>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    align: 'center'

<ScreenOne>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN ONE'
        font_size:50

<ScreenTwo>:
    Label:
        text: 'SCREEN TWO'
        font_size:50

<MainScreen>:
    manager: manager
    rows: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1

    ToolBar:
        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen one'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'sone'

        ToolButton:
            text: 'Screen two'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'stwo'

    ScreenSwitcher:
        id: manager
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - ScreenTwo]